# jquery resizeable pushes other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

Dear Friends as you can see jquery resizeable plugin pushes my other div under other divs. how can i prevent this ?

jquery resizeable pushes other divs

[image: screenshot]

this is my code. what should i do ?

```
$( "#satir21, #satir22, #satir1 , #satir3" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  change: function( event, ui ) {

    $( "#"+ui.helper.attr("id") ).resizable({
      containment: "#"+$(this).attr("id"),
      handles : "s"
    });       

  }
}).disableSelection();  

$( ".kutular" ).resizable({
  containment: "#satir21, #satir22"
});
```

Comment: The image isn't very helpful.  Could you make a working fiddle instead?

Comment: is not anybody who can help me ?

Comment: Please publish your HTML and CSS too.  Then put it in a fiddle so someone can easily tinker with your code and hopefully help you out. :)